# how to get list of installed cultures on computer?

Tags: culture

users usually install 2 or 3 cultures on their computers. we can reach current and all installed language with:

```
InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage;
InputLanguage.InstalledInputLanguages;
```

we can also reach current culture with:

```
CultureInfo currentCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
```

but is there a way for found out which cultures they installed. or the only way is to change language that he\she installed and get cultures. I think there is a better an smarter way.

Comment: Which system/language/API are you working in?

Comment: I want it work on windows/ all languages